# Run jar file with command line arguments

Tags: java, jar

How can I run a jar file in command prompt and pass arguments to it.

ie: "`test.jar -get`" would be entered in command prompt/terminal

Comment: You want run above command from eclipse command window? You question is little ambiguious.

Answer (score 77):

For the question

> How can i run a jar file in command prompt but with arguments

.

To pass arguments to the jar file at the time of execution

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2
```

In the main() method of "Main-Class" [mentioned in the manifest.mft file]of your JAR file. you can retrieve them like this:

```
String arg1 = args[0];
String arg2 = args[1];
```

Comment: thank you so much, its been bothering me ***forever***

Comment: "no main manifest attribute, in test.jar"

Comment: then it is not a standalone jar file, it does not have any class with main method. You need to createe a class and use that jar file as library. you need to import it in your class.

Comment: set the jar in the CLASSPATH variable and import it in your class. call whatever API you want to call. cant help you more than this, until and unless i know what you are trying to do, and what your jar file is

Comment: How could I pass arguments to the jar file, when using -cp 'a.jar:b.jar'? (-jar is ignored when -cp is set)

Comment: @Kiril when -jar is used, -cp is ignored. the quickest way(if you do not have too many jar files you want to use with -cp), is to not use the -jar, but use -cp instead with the option value of -jar also appended to the end of option values of -cp. Then specify the entry point class. So it would look like: java -cp a.jar:b.jar:YOURJARFILETORUN.jar MAINCLASS arg1 arg2 ..      where MAINCLASS is the fully quailified name of the class in which the 'main' method is defined in YOURJARFILETORUN.jar   Hope this makes sense

Comment: what in case of a shell script? Is there any change?